# Cannot get data from InputStream of a socket

Tags: java, sockets

Fail to read/write data to socket when trying to run echo server. No exception thrown and there is no response to console input. What's not correct in code?

```
public class Server {

    static ServerSocket server;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        String hostname = "127.0.0.1";

        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(8888); 
          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port 8888");
            System.exit(-1);
          }

        Socket theSocket = null;
        try {
            theSocket = new Socket(hostname, 8888);

            BufferedReader networkIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader userIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(theSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("Connected to echo server");

            while (true) {
              String theLine = userIn.readLine();
              if (theLine.equals("."))
                break;
              out.println(theLine);
              out.flush();
              System.out.println("networkIn: "+networkIn.readLine());
            }
            networkIn.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("out.close();");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created two unrelated sockets, one for accepting connections, and one for connecting to (hostname,8888). You need to call `accept()` on the server socket to actually get clients connected. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding `Socket client = server.accept();`. Then you'll see how you need to restructure the rest of your program.